# Cannot see PMD violations in Sonar

Tags: ant, sonarqube

Am new to sonar and using ant
I can get Junit report.But iam not getting Pmd report.
So please help me to solve the issue
Thanks
My build.xml is

```
  <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />  

  <property name="sonar.tests" value="${junit.output.dir}" />  

  <property name="sonar.binaries" value="bin" />  
    <property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports"/>

<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${junit.output.dir}" />  

  <property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="pmd_report.xml"/>

    <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="cobertura"/>
    <property name="sonar.cobertura.reportPath" value="${dir.coverage}/coverage.xml"/>



    <sonar:sonar key="com.sample:research1" version="0.3-SNAPSHOT" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To see pmd violations you should enable the PMD rules in your quality profile. It seems that it's not yet enabled. This page might be helpful : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-ConfiguringRules

Comment: Actually i just want to reuse the report already produced by the pmd.

Comment: I don't think that this feature is supported, but why would you ever want to reuse PMD reports if Sonar can generate that for you?

Comment: Import of PMD reports is not supported. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15242615/229031.