# Pmd violations with sonar

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

I just need a clarification about PMD with Sonar.Can we reuse Pmd reportwhich is already produced by ant..Else sonar will dynamically produce its own violation using PMD.
Please help me out...For past two days iam stucked up with this.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to import PMD nor Checkstyle reports. This is not the philosophy of Sonar.

Nothing guarantees that PMD has been executed with the configuration (Quality Profile) declared in sonar. It would lead to inconsistent results. Moreover why executing PMD by yourself while sonar does it for you ?